# Справочники или enum в Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Возникла проблема при моделировании БД.

Впервые пишу проект на Entity Framework Core. Раньше, когда я изучал SSMS и SQL, я всегда использовал таблицы-справочники. В текущем проекте я также создал несколько таких таблиц (и вероятно создам в будущем еще). Например, есть таблица **Item**, с которой связаны два справочника **ItemCategory** и **Quality** с помощью ключей **ItemCategoryId** и **QualityId** соответственно.

Но недавно в одном видео-гайде по ASP.NET я увидел как человек использовал enum. После увиденного возникла мысль переделать все мои справочники в enum. Это весьма сильно облегчило бы процесс создания бизнес-логики, но правильно ли это с точки зрения базы данных? Ранее я слышал, что enum в БД - плохая практика, но во время поиска информации в интернете мне показалось, что использование enum в Entity Framework Core - обычная практика, и поэтому я запутался.

Разбирающиеся люди, пожалуйста, помогите мне узнать истину. Все же стоит использовать справочники или enum? В чем преимущества и недостатки подходов? Что вы используете в своих проектах? Мне правда нужно это знать, но к сожалению спустя долгое время я так и не смог найти ничего полезного в интернете.

Comment: Это хороший вопрос. Насколько я помню, когда в одном проекте у нас стоял такой вопрос мы в итоге использовали и то и другое. Потому что перечисления удобны с точки зрения ООП, а справочники были нужны, когда работа с базой шла через `SQL`, без использования программного кода. Поскольку с базой работали и так и так, приходилось делать такое вот дублирование. Оно по-своему удобно, но получается нужно как-то поддерживать соответствие кода и таблиц при любых изменениях. Но если эти справочники редко меняются, то такой вариант удобен.

Comment: Я устроился на работу программиста с августа 2022 года. Моим удивлением было то, что есть данные, которые можно хранить в Enum и эти ключи передавать в базу в качестве Id. Поэтому это нормальная практика  в целом если значения в течение долго времени не обновляются. Если данные динамичны из Enum, то их следует выносить в базу. Как я понял вопрос заключался именно в этом

Comment: Условно список постоянных поставщиков, чьё количество не превышает 10-ти и которые всегда присутствуют

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь. Думаю, я разобрался с этим